# Answering the terminal questions from a GUI window

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to run terminal commands within a python file. It is working fine and I can also get the terminal messages on a gui window using subprocess.Popen.

```
import subprocess
import wx
import os
def main():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    text = p.stdout.readlines()
    text = "".join(text)

    wx.MessageBox("file names:\n%s" % text, "info")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    main()
```

But when I run a command for which terminal should ask answers of some questions, I am getting error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "to_make_new_project_folder.py", line 19, in <module> main() 
    File "to_make_new_project_folder.py", line 10, in main p = subprocess.Popen(['gr_modtool add -t general square_ff'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in init errread, errwrite)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Does someone have idea how to answer the question from terminal using a gui window?

Comment: Post the full stack trace, not just a piece of it. The piece you posted indicates that a child exception is being raised, but you're not showing us what that is.

Comment: It is the complete error that I am getting:                 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "to_make_new_project_folder.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "to_make_new_project_folder.py", line 10, in main
    p = subprocess.Popen(['gr_modtool add -t general square_ff'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: where "gr_modtool add -t general square_ff" is the command that I want to run on terminal and this command asks question from user.

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing in stdin=PIPE as well to popen

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace, the error you're receiving is `OSError: No such file or directory`, coming up from `subprocess`. It looks to me like `Popen` can't find the file that you're trying to execute, and is therefore failing.

Comment: I am using the same file with 'ls' command and it is working fine. But when I use 'gr_modtool add -t general square_ff' command it gives me the error.